# Disease causing variants and Hardy-Weinberg Equilibrium

Tags: genetics, pathology, mutations, population-genetics, hardy-weinberg

Is it true that many disease causing variants/mutations do not follow Hardy Weinberg Equilibrium?  If so, then please elaborate on why this may be true (or not) and provide examples.

I am interested in single-gene disorders or those linked with single nucleotide variants.  I was told that many disease causing variants/mutations do not follow Hardy Weinberg Equilibrium, but I cannot find any documentation showing this (so I am looking for a reference on this matter).  In particular, I have considered Huntington's disease, Sickle cell anaemia and Hemophilia, but have not found any special relationships with these diseases and HWE.

Thank you.

Comment: Welcome to Biology.SE. Homework questions are considered off-topic **unless** the OP shows attempts of answering its own question.

Comment: This is not a homework question. I am a research data analyst proposing a bioinformatics model and I imagine the answer to this question will be helpful to my work.  I have done much searching, even considering HWE along with single-gene disorders such as Huntington's disease, Sickle cell anaemia and Hemophilia. I turned to StackExchange because my searches have proved unfruitful thus far. Thank you.

Comment: Ok, I retracted my close vote!

Comment: @user918804 in that case, please [edit] your question and add more details as to what you've already looked at, what you've learned, and what **exactly** you're still having problems with. Citations would also be helpful. The more detailed a question, the better the chances of getting a good detailed answer.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

[Hardy-Weinberg law](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Hardy%E2%80%93Weinberg_principle) makes a series of assumptions. One of them is the absence of selective effects. As you talk about disease, this assumption of neutrality is obviously not met.

**At the moment of fecundation**

Imagine for example that at the moment of the fecundation, the genotypes `AA`, `Aa` and `aa` are at Hardy-Weinberg equilibrium. Let `x` be the frequency of the allele `A` at the moment of fecundation, the frequencies of the genotypes `AA`, `Aa` and `aa` are $x^2$, $2x(1-x)$ and $(1-x)^2$, respectively.

**After selection**

As all genotypes `aa` die off, you're left with the `A` allele being at frequency $y=2x^2 + x(1-x)=x(1+x)$ and the frequencies of the genotypes `AA`, `Aa` and `aa` are $\frac{x^2}{x^2 + 2x(1-x)}=\frac{2x-2}{x-2}$, $\frac{2x(1-x)}{x^2 + 2x(1-x)}=\frac{x}{2-x}$, and $0$, respectively.

**Expressing the genotype frequencies in terms of the new allele frequency**

You can as well plug $y$ into those genotype frequencies to get the expression in terms of the genotype frequencies at birth ($y$; after selection). It gives you $\frac{1-\sqrt{4 y+1}}{\sqrt{4 y+1}-5}$, $\frac{2 \left(\sqrt{4 y+1}-3\right)}{\sqrt{4 y+1}-5}$ and $0$ for the genotypes `AA`, `Aa` and `aa` respectively. So, obviously, it is not at Hardy-Weinberg equilibrium.

**Assumptions**

You can make some more interesting calculations by leaving out the assumptions that all `aa` genotypes die at birth and you could use a Leslie matrix to describe the probability for an individual of each genotype to make to the next age. I also assumed that the `a` is completely recessive. You might want to release this assumption as well by computing the death of a fraction of the `Aa` genotypes.

Comment: I welcome the readers to double check my calculations.

Comment: I think the real surprising effect is the rather high frequency of the sickness causing alleles. For sickle cell anemia there is a well-known explanation, but I am wondering about Huntington Chorea.

Answer (score 0):

In the case of sickle cell anemia, there is a positive selection effect of the illness causing gene variant: Heterozygous gene carriers have some immunity against malaria. Therefore, sickle cell anemia is quite frequent in malaria affected regions of the world.